# Update SQL Server Table with pyodbc conditional on date

Tags: sql-server, pandas, datetime, sql-update, pyodbc

Trying to update a Microsoft Server SQL Table column. I am using pyodbc library to do so. Somehow, I am getting an error that seems to be complaining about the date match conditional.

Note: the SQL Server field type for date_time column (in the Database) is 'date'

Dataframe (used to update the DB table) summary:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 4 columns):

SID                     100000 non-null object
prod                    100000 non-null object
Response Date           100000 non-null object
RId                     100000 non-null object

dtypes: int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 8.4+ MB
```

dataframe 'data' Date field:

```
data['Response Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Response Date'], infer_datetime_format = True).dt.date

data['Response Date']
Out[139]: 
0        2019-11-25
1        2019-11-25
2        2019-11-25
3        2019-11-25
4        2019-11-25

99995    2019-05-21
99996    2019-05-21
99997    2019-05-21
99998    2019-05-21
99999    2019-05-21
Name: Response Date, Length: 100000, dtype: object
```

Statement used to execute the update

```
cursor.execute("Update dbo.dtable set dbprod = '%s' where dbrid = '%s'and date_time = '%s' and dbsid = '%s'" % (data['prod'], data['RId'], data['Response Date'], data['SID']))
```

Error

> DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 0):

It's really important to use a standard SQL Server date format when you're sending it strings that contain date values. In the code above, it's unlikely that you're achieving that.

To check, print the `data['Response Date']` value as a string and check out the format that you currently have.

For SQL Server, you really want to be sending datetime values in this format `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` and note I don't have any slashes or dashes in there.